# How split a big method to smaller several methods in C#

Tags: c#, oop, optimization, refactoring

How can I optimally split one big, difficult method to several smaller methods in **C#**? Is there any perception or functionality for this issue?

Comment: THis is often a matter of taste. Please add an outline of your specific case.

Comment: Please add your big method code. You have to think this way: in one method you can't create a car, start the car and drive the car. Instead you create 3 methods one to create, one to start and one to drive the car.

Comment: @Mivaweb unless you want to create a method handleTransportation() in which you create a car, start and drive it

Comment: I downvoted, because you question is very broad and you did not provide an example or what you tried to do. The issue its self is quite common and one of the biggest pains in development. If you are really interested, I suggest to learn about SOLID-Principles of object oriented design. I can further recommend the book **Clean Code** by Robert C. Martin which covers in detail how to write code that is easy to understand, maintain and to extend.

Comment: to make code readable usually if method contains big nested loops or if-else conditions  its better to extract them into methods. and do it over and over till the method is understandable and small enough.

Comment: DrKoch: It is definitely not matter of taste, and also development is not matter of taste, because it a _profession_. There are common know-how, best practices etc. The question is indeed good, although obviously newbie, but that's not a problem. To all who require the concrete code: Its better to give a general advice answer. "give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime". The question is useful and completely answerable in a useful way as Discosultan did it. "It is written in some book" is not an argument to downvote.

Comment: Hi , thank you , for yours recommendations, i have copied example in the last answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using Visual Studio to edit your C# code, there is built-in functionality for what you are trying to do: [Extract Method Refactoring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0s21cwxk.aspx). Note that this is still a manual process - there is no automatic tool which knows how to take your entire method apart.

---

What to keep in mind while refactoring? Taken from Robert C. Martin's Clean Code:

> - The first rule of functions is that they should be small. The second rule of functions is that they should be smaller than that.
> - Functions should do one thing. They should do it well. They should do it only.
> - We want the code to read like a top-down narrative.
> - Use descriptive names.
> - The ideal number of arguments for a function is
>   zero (niladic). Next comes one (monadic), followed
>   closely by two (dyadic). Three arguments (triadic)
>   should be avoided where possible. More than three
>   (polyadic) requires very special justification